# Widgets not showing up in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Im trying to do the layout below with flexible widgets so when the screen size changes the layout stays about the same but when I put a flexible widget around a column anything that I put in the column in not visible. What am I doing wrong?

Wanted Outcome

[image]

What I have

[image]

My code

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 9,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice drawing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Finish your work, you will get the thing you have asked***

Provide child on container

```
 Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                        width: double.infinity,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm new to flutter so I didn't realize that you needed to have a child in a Container to have it display.